# Bootstrap Accordion show what is clicked on the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3ah26cvq/

In the JSFiddle by default HTML is active and it consist of 11 questions in it. And now PHP by default it is collapsed, and when we click on it, it will open, and HTML will collapse.

My problem is when I click on PHP it is showing the last question of PHP.! In my case it is **Focusing (showing)** 11th question of PHP, Actually it should **Focus (show)** the PHP title because we clicked it.! How can I achieve it.?

Related to the above JSFiddle

I have tried with 3 different ways but none are working:

```
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });
```

In short what every I click it should focus on the screen how can I do that?

```js
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){ $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){ $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){ $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });
```

```css
.circle {
  width: auto;
  height: 23px;
  text-align:top;
  float: right;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #fff;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.panel_heading_bg {
  background-color: #122c5f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMain">
    <?php /* HTML */ ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseHTML">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>H</b></span>HTML</a> </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseHTML" class="panel-collapse collapse in " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionHTML">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML3">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML4">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML5">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML6">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML7">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML8">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML9">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML10">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML11">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* HTML  END */ ?>
            <?php /* PHP */ ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapsePHP" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>P</b></span>PHP</a> </h4> </div>
                    <div id="collapsePHP" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                        <div class="panel-body ">
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordionPHP">
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP1">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP2">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP3">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP4">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP5">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP6">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP7">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP8">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP9">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP10">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP11">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php /* PHP  END */ ?>
                    <?php /* JAVASCRIPT */ ?>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseJavaScript" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>JS</b></span>JAVASCRIPT</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseJavaScript" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">
                                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionJavaScript">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript1">
                                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                            <div id="collapseJavaScript1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript2">
                                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                            <div id="collapseJavaScript2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php /* JAVASCRIPT  END */ ?>
                            <?php /* MYSQL */ ?>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseMYSQL" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>SQL</b></span>MYSQL</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMYSQL">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL1">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php /* MYSQL  END */ ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not an issue, you have used a bootstrap accordion, it is a default function. In this case, you can use bootstrap collapse. When you click on the PHP, manually collapses the other tabs.

Comment: The issue is with the Accordion title focus, you need to use `scrollTop` to add the behavior.

Comment: It's unclear what you meant by 'focus'. I saw the fiddle, it's working pretty much the way it should. Can you elaborate @asif

Comment: @asif You got a space `50px` between the first question and the top title item you need to do a condition on this value to got the good property for the other question when scrolled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just adding a condition when the question isn't the first *because got the parent title* give a space `-50px`. I added a fake class inside `<a>` to help us to known the parents clicked before scroll... etc

```js
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });

$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
    //console.log("TEST TEST : " + $(this).find('h4 a').prop('class'));
    if ($(this).find('h4 a').prop('class') === 'parents') {

        //console.log("ok parent");
        var target = $(this).find('h4 a').prop('class');
        //console.log("target = " + target)
        /* le sélecteur $(html, body) permet de corriger un bug sur chrome 
        et safari (webkit) */
        $('html, body')
          // on arrête toutes les animations en cours 
          .stop()
          /* on fait maintenant l'animation vers le haut (scrollTop) vers 
          notre ancre target */

          .animate({ scrollTop: $('.' + target).offset().top }, 1000);
    } else {
        //console.log($(this).prop('class'));
        // console.log(typeof parseInt($(this).find('b').text()))
        if ($(this).find('b').text() != 1 && ($(this).find('h4 a').prop('class') !== 'parents')) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 50 }, 800);
        } else if ($(this).find('h4 a').prop('class') !== 'parents') {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 800);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: auto;
  height: 23px;
  text-align:top;
  float: right;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #fff;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.panel_heading_bg {
  background-color: #122c5f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMain">
    <?php /* HTML */ ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseHTML">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a class="parents"><span class="circle"><b>HTML</b></span>HTML</a> </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseHTML" class="panel-collapse collapse in " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionHTML">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML3">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML4">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML5">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a></h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML6">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML7">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML8">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML9">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML10">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML11">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapsePHP" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a class="parents"><span class="circle"><b>P</b></span>PHP</a> </h4> </div>
            <div id="collapsePHP" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionPHP">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP3">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP4">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP5">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP6">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP7">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP8">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP9">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP10">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a></h4></div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP11">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapsePHP11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseJavaScript" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a class="parents"><span class="circle"><b>JS</b></span>JAVASCRIPT</a> </h4> </div>
            <div id="collapseJavaScript" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionJavaScript">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseJavaScript1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseJavaScript2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseMYSQL" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a class="parents"><span class="circle"><b>SQL</b></span>MYSQL</a> </h4> </div>
            <div id="collapseMYSQL" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMYSQL">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseMYSQL1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseMYSQL2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when we click on php it should scroll to php title or first question of php but now it is staying at php question 10,11.  i hope you understand my question.

Comment: @asif i did a ajustement in french ;) https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/bYNrjB

Answer (score 1):

can you see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ah26cvq/2/)? I think it will help.

```js
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function() { $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });

$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 800);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: auto;
  height: 23px;
  text-align:top;
  float: right;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #fff;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.panel_heading_bg {
  background-color: #122c5f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMain">
    <?php /* HTML */ ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseHTML">
                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>H</b></span>HTML</a> </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseHTML" class="panel-collapse collapse in " style="cursor:pointer">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionHTML">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML1">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML2">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML3">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML4">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML5">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML6">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML7">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML8">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML9">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML10">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapseHTML11">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseHTML11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* HTML  END */ ?>
            <?php /* PHP */ ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapsePHP" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>P</b></span>PHP</a> </h4> </div>
                    <div id="collapsePHP" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                        <div class="panel-body ">
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordionPHP">
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP1">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP2">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP3">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question3</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP3" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP4">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question4</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP4" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP5">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question5</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP5" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer5</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP6">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question6</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP6" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer6</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionPHP" href="#collapsePHP7">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question7</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP7" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer7</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP8">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question8</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP8" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer8</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP9">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question9</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP9" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer9</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP10">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question10</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP10" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer10</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionHTML" href="#collapsePHP11">
                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question11</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapsePHP11" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer11</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php /* PHP  END */ ?>
                    <?php /* JAVASCRIPT */ ?>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseJavaScript" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>JS</b></span>JAVASCRIPT</a> </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseJavaScript" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                                <div class="panel-body ">
                                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionJavaScript">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript1">
                                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                            <div id="collapseJavaScript1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionJavaScript" href="#collapseJavaScript2">
                                            <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                            <div id="collapseJavaScript2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php /* JAVASCRIPT  END */ ?>
                            <?php /* MYSQL */ ?>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMain" href="#collapseMYSQL" class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>SQL</b></span>MYSQL</a> </h4> </div>
                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL" class="panel-collapse collapse " style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <div class="panel-body ">
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMYSQL">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL1">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>1</b></span>question1</a> </h4> </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL1" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer1</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMYSQL" href="#collapseMYSQL2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading_bg" style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title "><a><span class="circle"><b>2</b></span>question2</a> </h4> </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseMYSQL2" class="panel-collapse collapse '+collap+' " style="cursor:pointer">
                                                        <div class="panel-body ">answer2</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php /* MYSQL  END */ ?>
</div>
```

I have added scrollTop jQuery function. Nothing else.

Comment: Little improved but still issue is there when you click on the PHP it should focus now it is focusing php question 10,11. @kumar

Comment: yea, its working mate. You can add more content end of the collapsible section then you will see. Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/3ah26cvq/5/

Because if there isn't sufficient white space under of it then it can't go to top.